# NAV referenced service not working after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, nav

I have ASP.NET core 5 web API that communicates with NAV referenced service using WCF in C# everything is fine when I'm running the app in visual studio but when I publish the project to the server I get **500 error** on every endpoint that is using referenced service. here is the error log:

```
Dec 06 13:43:49 spardev.local spo-api[14418]: fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
Dec 06 13:43:49 spardev.local spo-api[14418]:       Connection id "0HMDONPM621RV", Request id "0HMDONPM621RV:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Dec 06 13:43:49 spardev.local spo-api[14418]:       System.PlatformNotSupportedException: NTLM authentication is not possible with default credentials on this platform.
```

I have even served the project on my local **IIS** but I get the same error.

What is the problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: NTLM authentication is not possible with default credentials on this platform.`Maybe you can try to change the default credentials.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699918/use-ntlm-authentication-in-web-request-in-net-core &&https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68115433/iis-log-fail-microsoft-aspnetcore-server-kestrel13-jwtbeareroptions

Comment: @LanHuang Thank you for your comment but my credentials are working on my local computer.

Comment: Maybe you can provide more detailed error information.These are similar errors you can refer to https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19476 
&  https://github.com/BryanWilhite/Songhay.Blog/issues/18  & 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38469054/kestrel-error-on-a-netcore-web-api-app-on-a-dev-machine-but-not-on-another